# Qt static. Building static application

Tags: linux, qt, static

I need to build statically linked application using Qt framework.

I have Qt5.7.1, installed from standart repository of my packet manager (my OS is Arch Linux). QtCreator was installed in the same way.

Then I've built another Qt5.7.1 from source by the folowing commands:

```
../configure -static --prefix=/home/accumplus/soft/Qt5.7.1_static/ -release -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -qt-sql-sqlite -make libs -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg
make -j8
make install
```

Then, looking for some guide, I've added Qt Version "Qt5.7.1_static"(Tools->Options->Build&Run->Qt Versions), specifying qmake location: "/home/accumplus/soft/Qt5.7.1_static/bin/qmake".

Added Kit (Tools->Options->Build&Run->Kits). The only option I've changed is "Qt version", set it to just added.

Then tried to build simple Qt Widgets application and got a large amount of "undefined reference" errors, mostly connected with pthread, png, hb, ucol, ucal and pcre functions.

Where am I wrong?

P.S. Creator shows me "No qmlscene installed" while adding new Qt version. Maybe this information will be useful. Also if there will be project configuration options, I used to use CMake than qmake.

Comment: What the 'Prefix' setting value in qt.conf file at the qmake location?

Comment: @AlexanderVX There are a lot of folders for different compilers, I guess... There is _linux-g++_ folder, and its qmake.conf file includes some other .conf files. But even connecting them all, I can't see 'Prefix' setting.

Comment: You need to make sure that correct qmake is running and there is qt.conf pointing to correct build.